# Multi Join Table in Mysql returning only one row

Tags: mysql, join, select, row, mysql-workbench

Hi I am seeking help with my code, currently it is returning only one row and I am utterly stuck with this one and cant seem to fix it. I'm hoping another persons insight could help me.

```
use library;

#3
Select title, count(loanId) as 'Number of loans'
From book
     Join bookCopy ON bookCopy.isbn = book.isbn
     Join loan ON bookCopy.copyId = loan.copyId
Where dateBack IS NULL
Order By title;
```

Comment: You forgot `GROUP BY title`

Comment: Your query is not valid SQL without a `group by` which MySql is [allowing you to get away with](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by)

Answer (score 0):

That is because COUNT.

use GROUP BY title

```
Select title, count(loanId) as 'Number of loans'
From book
     Join bookCopy ON bookCopy.isbn = book.isbn
     Join loan ON bookCopy.copyId = loan.copyId
Where dateBack IS NULL
GROUP BY title
Order By title;
```